# Select EF entities that have all the given Tags (where tag is an EF entity)

Tags: c#, .net, linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I have the following situation:
An "Conversations" entity/table which has multiple Tags associated to it.
Tag is also an entity/table - the key/id is tagName (a string).

On the client side (javascript) I work with arrays of string when dealing with Tags.

*Now I want want to retrieve all the conversations that have **all** given tags.*

---

The input is an array of strings and the output should be a collection of Conversations

I've tried:

```
var filterTags = new List<EFModels.Tag>();
foreach (var tagName in tags)
            {
               filterTags.Add(new EFModels.Tag() { Name = tagName});
            }

var conversations = from c in context.Conversations where !c.Tags.Except(filterTags).Any() select c ;
```

The problem with this is: `Unable to create a constant value of type 'EFModels.Tag'. Only primitive types or enumeration types are supported in this context` - which makes sense.

Now how can I do my select? What's the best approach? (I still want to use linq and not write the sql select)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can project c.Tags to tag name.

I guess it will look like that

```
var conversations = from c in context.Conversations where !c.Tags.Select(tag => tag.Name ).Except(filterTags).Any() select c ;
```

Where filterTags is the list of strings containing the names of the tags

Comment: This does the trick - thanks. I had to change my query to var conversations = from c in context.Conversations where !tags.Except(c.Tags.Select(tag => tag.Name)).Any() select c ; and now it works correctly.
One things bothers me though - performance. Anything else I can do/change so increase the performance of the query?

Comment: Depends on the size of the tag names collection. I believe that the performance will not suffer. Anyway since the tag names are in memory this will generate sql query which will be.. sth... where Tags in(tag1,tag2...tagN). You should keep in mind that if the tag names collection is too long (more than 2000 elements), the query will fail, because the in statement supports up to 2000 parameters.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up regarding the parameters - I'll have to run some tests to see the performance decay/impact.